# Why psql doing nothing with -h param?

Tags: postgresql, psql

I have installed postgres, then I created new user and opened md5 authentication on 127.0.0.1 in pg_hba.conf

```
# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     peer
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
```

But now if I try to connect via psql with "-h" flag with "127.0.0.1" and this user psql doing nothing.

```
-bash-4.2$ psql -h 127.0.0.1 -U k4fntr
```

it is just freez

Comment: Do you see a similar effect if you `ssh root@127.0.0.1`?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with iptables. I discovered that I had no something about postgres in iptables.

This command had fixed the problem

```
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp -m tcp -s 127.0.0.1 --dport 5432 -j ACCEPT
```